# How to solve the error in installing external module in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install termcolor
```

I have jupyter notebook installed through anaconda, whenever i try to install termcolor, it gives me this error and i have no idea how to tackle it.

[Error image](https://nustedupk0-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/aazfar_mse15scme_student_nust_edu_pk/ESpppa5AIW9KqAl0ZLteA9oBCCi2DPO1MnjC1MiOsiBFSA?e=7MoOHh)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\MY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: image attached for reference. Thank you.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a command in the command line via jupyter use `!`

`!pip install termcolor`

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver. Bless you. Have tried every possible thing on internet I could find.